# How to print a hidden div usign JQuery print library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [JQuery](https://doersguild.github.io/jQuery.print/). print library to print my html web pages. This javascript library takes by default displayed content, and I want to know if there's a possibility to print hidden elements.

```
$("#myElementId").print(/*options*/);
```

Comment: No need to use the library for it. You can separately specify print CSS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use media queries.

This is a good post https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/

```css
@media print {
 .hidden-but-printable {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is the best and in my opinion only correct way to do it without adding unnecessary javascript etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use media query for print styles as

```
@media print {
    .hidden-div{
        display:block;
    }
}
```