# Printing out functionally hidden elements

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, printing, hidden

I am hiding my table using c# in the back once the page is loaded like this:

```
FreqTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Visible = false;
FreqTable.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

Once the print button is pressed I initiate print function using javascript:

```
window.print();
```

I set the CSS of print media so it would be visible(no luck seems like the css is being ignored) and tried making the table visible once the button is clicked. There is small "but" I do not want it to be displayed onto my screen once the print button is clicked.

What would an approach here of printing an element that is hidden and not displaying it onto the screen?

Comment: you need to use a media query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626069/how-to-print-a-hidden-div-usign-jquery-print-library/44626155

Comment: read the question again please

Comment: the media query hides the elements, but will send it to the printer

Comment: im using chrome i can see the output of the document

Comment: see answer below by (Giacomo De Liberali) - using media query

Comment: nah wont work sorry

Comment: read question again

Comment: You need to make your question clearer, I don't understand the issue.  Can you expand on why this technique wont work for you, if you can?

Comment: I'm not hiding the element using css I'm hiding it dynamically once the button was clicked etc. It seems like css media query is being ignored..

Comment: are you doing a server round trip to hide it?  or could you have two css  - one to "show it" and one for "print only",  then hide it by removing the "show it" css, so it still has the "print only" css

Comment: Looks like you are hiding it on the server which means it is not rendered to the page. So you need to not hide it on the serverside, hide it with CSS and show it with print media

Comment: I’will repeat again the media query of display:block or any other way is being ignored. Probably because the elements are hidden using c# rather then css

Comment: @whiterabbitj If this many people have difficulties understanding your problem, maybe it's not them not having read your question properly, but the question being misleading.

Comment: I even express that the element is hidden is back of c# and media query is being ignored.. what is not clear could you help me to word it better sir @LonelyNeuron

Comment: @whiterabbitj I don't know enough about the topic to properly rephrase it. I am just trying to get you to be more aware of the fact that many people seem to misunderstand your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by displaying the elements after the print function in c# and hiding it using JavaScript function that is invoked after the elements were displayed.

So that way nothing is displayed but I can still print out the elements once I set the visibility in print media.

That would the right solution to this problem not some css media query....

Answer (score 3):

You can assign to the element you want only to print the following `print-only` class

```
.print-only {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .print-only{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: delete the answer please incorect

Comment: @whiterabbitj I understand this answer is correct too, maybe you should change the question, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: The answer is incorrect read the question again it’s pretty clear I even mention that media query is being ignored or what not

Comment: @whiterabbitj I am not sure if you are aware, but your way of writing comes across very rude and unfriendly. Which certainly is not appropriate considering someone is trying to solve your problem

Comment: no its not. its rude posting an obvious "solution" to my question in my opinion. It just misleads the people who come see the thread as the question seems to be "answered" @LonelyNeuron

Comment: @whiterabbitj I just meant to kindly make you aware that it could come across as rude - no matter if you meant it in a rude way. And no, answering questions with the best intentions is not rude. No matter how wrong the answers are

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I do not agree it was just a rushed answer from the person that saw something somewhere about print media queries...